# "Recursion depth exceeded error" while calculating the length of a string in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement the Karatsuba Algorithm as mentioned in the course here  in python 2.7. Here is the code that I have got currently:

```
# Karatsuba multiplication implementation in python

import numpy as np
import sys

# x = 10^(n/2)*a + b and y = 10^(n/2)*c + d
# x.y = 10^n*(ac) + 10^(n/2)*(ad + bc) + bd
# now recursively compute ac, ad, bc and bd

sys.setrecursionlimit(15000)

def algo_recurs(val1, val2):
  # Assuming that the length of both the multiplier and multiplicand is 
    same
  # Currently employing numbers which are of length 2^n
  n = len(str(val1))            # n = 4
  print(n)
  divVal    = 10**(n/2)
  a = val1 / divVal         # a = 12
  b = val1 % divVal         # b = 34
  c = val2 / divVal         # c = 43
  d = val2 % divVal         # d = 21
  # let the example case be 1234 * 4321

  if(len(str(val1)) == 2):
    prob1 = a * c
    prob2 = b * d
    prob3 = (a+b)*(c+d) - prob1 - prob2
    finalResult = prob1*(divVal*divVal)+prob3*divVal+prob2
    return(finalResult)
  else:
    prob1 = algo_recurs(a,c)
    prob2 = algo_recurs(b,d)
    prob3 = algo_recurs((a+b),(c+d)) - prob1 -prob2
    finalResult = prob1*(divVal*divVal)+prob3*divVal+prob2
    #print(finalResult)
    return(finalResult)
#Enter the inputs

multiplicand    = input("Enter the multiplicand:")
multiplier      = input("Enter the multiplier:")
output = algo_recurs(multiplicand, multiplier)  
print(output)
```

The above code works well with the numbers of length 4 or less. But the moment I go beyond that, it throws the following error:

```
File "Karatsuba.py", line 31, in algo_recurs
  prob1 = algo_recurs(a,c)
File "Karatsuba.py", line 31, in algo_recurs
  prob1 = algo_recurs(a,c)
File "Karatsuba.py", line 31, in algo_recurs
  prob1 = algo_recurs(a,c)
File "Karatsuba.py", line 15, in algo_recurs
  n = len(str(val1))            # n = 4
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

I increased the recursion limit too, thinking that it might have been the issue. But that didn't solve it either.

I would appreciate if you can point out what I might be doing wrong in the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm will never terminate, no matter how high you set the recursion limit. This is because the parameters a and c will always stay the same once `val1` gets to single digits, because then `n` is 1 and `10**(n/2)` is also 1.

Answer (score -1):

It's dangerous to change the recursion limit because typically when you have exceeded the recursion limit, it's because your program contains an error or a poor design decision. Recursion can always be replaced with iteration at equal or lower memory cost.

Unless your algorithm insists you to do so knowing that at some point you will receive a result, you can change the maximum recursion depth every time you call your function, but again I wouldn't recommend since your program exceeded 1500 recursive calls when you set it to that and that is quite excessive.

```
# Karatsuba multiplication implementation in python

import numpy as np
import sys

def algo_recurs(val1, val2):
    sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() + 1)  # Changes the recursion limit every time
    n = len(str(val1))
    #print(n)
    divVal = 10**(n/2)
    a = val1 / divVal         # a = 12
    b = val1 % divVal         # b = 34
    c = val2 / divVal         # c = 43
    d = val2 % divVal         # d = 21

    if(len(str(val1)) == 2):
        prob1 = a * c
        prob2 = b * d
        prob3 = (a+b)*(c+d) - prob1 - prob2
        finalResult = prob1*(divVal*divVal)+prob3*divVal+prob2
        return(finalResult)
    else:
        prob1 = algo_recurs(a,c)
        prob2 = algo_recurs(b,d)
        prob3 = algo_recurs((a+b),(c+d)) - prob1 -prob2
        finalResult = prob1*(divVal*divVal)+prob3*divVal+prob2
        return(finalResult)

multiplicand    = int(input("Enter the multiplicand:"))
multiplier      = int(input("Enter the multiplier:"))
output = algo_recurs(multiplicand, multiplier)  
print(output)
```

Comment: I am also skeptical that there might be something wrong in the implementation of the algorithm above. But I just need another pair of eyes which can spot where I might be gping wrong

Comment: If you want more information on this particular algorithm and its issues, check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058838/karatsuba-algorithm-too-much-recursion