# `repr` and `int` take quadratic time in Python

Tags: python, int, runtime, asymptotic-complexity, repr

I was making a table of different run-times for Python 2.7, and noticed a thing that I cannot explain: The run-time of `repr(2**n)` and `int('1'*n)` is `O(n^2)`. I always assumed that converting between integer and string would be `O(n)` with `n` being number of digits. The results show that if `O(n)` fitting gives ~30% error, while `O(n^2)` is only ~5%.

Could anyone explain please.

Here are the results that I get (codes are below):

```
Test Number-1 -- time to compute int('1'*n) (fit to O(n**2))
Spec_string:  1000<=n<=10000 by factors of 2
var_list ['n']
Function list: ('n**2', 'n', '1')
run times:
n =   1000 : 10.045052 microseconds
n =   2000 : 35.215855 microseconds
n =   4000 : 141.801834 microseconds
n =   8000 : 480.597973 microseconds
Coefficients as interpolated from data:
 7.17731e-06*n**2
+0.00487043*n
-2.0574*1
(measuring time in microseconds)
Sum of squares of residuals: 0.00673433934709
RMS error = 4.1 percent

Test Number-2 -- time to compute repr(2**n) (fit to O(n**2))
Spec_string:  1000<=n<=10000 by factors of 2
var_list ['n']
Function list: ('n**2', 'n', '1')
run times:
n =   1000 : 1.739025 microseconds
n =   2000 : 6.217957 microseconds
n =   4000 : 29.226065 microseconds
n =   8000 : 102.524042 microseconds
Coefficients as interpolated from data:
 1.72846e-06*n**2
-0.000434518*n
+0.433448*1
(measuring time in microseconds)
Sum of squares of residuals: 0.0139070140697
RMS error = 5.9 percent

Test Number-3 -- time to compute int('1'*n) (fit to O(n))
Spec_string:  1000<=n<=10000 by factors of 2
var_list ['n']
Function list: ('n', '1')
run times:
n =   1000 : 10.187864 microseconds
n =   2000 : 37.642002 microseconds
n =   4000 : 128.378153 microseconds
n =   8000 : 492.624998 microseconds
Coefficients as interpolated from data:
 0.0380857*n
-28.5106*1
(measuring time in microseconds)
Sum of squares of residuals: 0.268768241745
RMS error = 26 percent

Test Number-4 -- time to compute repr(2**n) (fit to O(n))
Spec_string:  1000<=n<=10000 by factors of 2
var_list ['n']
Function list: ('n', '1')
run times:
n =   1000 : 1.750946 microseconds
n =   2000 : 6.271839 microseconds
n =   4000 : 30.361176 microseconds
n =   8000 : 102.671146 microseconds
Coefficients as interpolated from data:
 0.0070098*n
-5.40096*1
(measuring time in microseconds)
Sum of squares of residuals: 0.467752717824
RMS error = 34 percent
```

Below are the codes and the results. You can ignore the support functions in the code (`lg`, `sqrt`, `make_param_list`, `fit`, `fit2`)

`main.py`:

```
from .support import *

def test_number():
    print
    print "Test Number-1 -- time to compute int('1'*n) (fit to O(n**2))"
    spec_string = "1000<=n<=10000"
    growth_factor = 2
    print "Spec_string: ",spec_string,"by factors of",growth_factor
    var_list, param_list = make_param_list(spec_string,growth_factor)
    f_list = ("n**2","n","1")
    run_times = []
    trials = 1000
    for D in param_list:
        t = timeit.Timer("string.atoi(x)","import string;x='1'*%(n)s"%D)
        run_times.append(t.timeit(trials)*1e6/float(trials))
    fit(var_list,param_list,run_times,f_list)

    print
    print "Test Number-2 -- time to compute repr(2**n) (fit to O(n**2))"
    spec_string = "1000<=n<=10000"
    growth_factor = 2
    print "Spec_string: ",spec_string,"by factors of",growth_factor
    var_list, param_list = make_param_list(spec_string,growth_factor)
    f_list = ("n**2","n","1")
    run_times = []
    trials = 1000
    for D in param_list:
        t = timeit.Timer("repr(x)","x=2**%(n)s"%D)
        run_times.append(t.timeit(trials)*1e6/float(trials))
    fit(var_list,param_list,run_times,f_list)

    print
    print "Test Number-3 -- time to compute int('1'*n) (fit to O(n))"
    spec_string = "1000<=n<=10000"
    growth_factor = 2
    print "Spec_string: ",spec_string,"by factors of",growth_factor
    var_list, param_list = make_param_list(spec_string,growth_factor)
    f_list = ("n","1")
    run_times = []
    trials = 1000
    for D in param_list:
        t = timeit.Timer("string.atoi(x)","import string;x='1'*%(n)s"%D)
        run_times.append(t.timeit(trials)*1e6/float(trials))
    fit(var_list,param_list,run_times,f_list)

    print
    print "Test Number-4 -- time to compute repr(2**n) (fit to O(n))"
    spec_string = "1000<=n<=10000"
    growth_factor = 2
    print "Spec_string: ",spec_string,"by factors of",growth_factor
    var_list, param_list = make_param_list(spec_string,growth_factor)
    f_list = ("n","1")
    run_times = []
    trials = 1000
    for D in param_list:
        t = timeit.Timer("repr(x)","x=2**%(n)s"%D)
        run_times.append(t.timeit(trials)*1e6/float(trials))
    fit(var_list,param_list,run_times,f_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_number()
```

`support.py`:

```
import math
import string
import timeit
import scipy.optimize

def lg(x):
    return math.log(x)/math.log(2.0)

def sqrt(x):
    return math.sqrt(x)

def make_param_list(spec_string,growth_factor):
    """
    Generate a list of dictionaries
    given maximum and minimum values for each range.
    Each min and max value is a *string* that can be evaluted;
    each string may depend on earlier variable values
    Values increment by factor of growth_factor from min to max
    Example:
       make_param_list("1<=n<=1000")
       make_param_list("1<=n<=1000;1<=m<=1000;min(n,m)<=k<=max(n,m)")
    """
    var_list = []
    spec_list = string.split(spec_string,";")
    D = {}
    D['lg']=lg
    D['sqrt'] = sqrt
    D_list = [D]
    for spec in spec_list:
        spec_parts = string.split(spec,"<=")
        assert len(spec_parts)==3
        lower_spec = spec_parts[0]
        var_name = spec_parts[1]
        assert len(var_name)==1
        var_list.append(var_name)
        upper_spec = spec_parts[2]
        new_D_list = []
        for D in D_list:
            new_D = D.copy()
            val = eval(lower_spec,D)
            while val<=eval(upper_spec,D):
                new_D[var_name] = val
                new_D_list.append(new_D.copy())
                val *= growth_factor
        D_list = new_D_list
    return (var_list,D_list)

def fit(var_list,param_list,run_times,f_list):
    """
    Return matrix A needed for least-squares fit.
    Given:
        list of variable names
        list of sample dicts for various parameter sets
        list of corresponding run times
        list of functions to be considered for fit
            these are *strings*, e.g. "n","n**2","min(n,m)",etc.
    prints:
        coefficients for each function in f_list
    """
    print "var_list",var_list
    print "Function list:",f_list
    print "run times:",
    for i in range(len(param_list)):
        print
        for v in var_list:
            print v,"= %6s"%param_list[i][v],
        print ": %8f"%run_times[i],"microseconds",
    print
    rows = len(run_times)
    cols = len(f_list)
    A = [ [0 for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows) ]
    for i in range(rows):
        D = param_list[i]
        for j in range(cols):
            A[i][j] = float(eval(f_list[j],D))
    b = run_times

    (x,resids,rank,s) = fit2(A,b)

    print "Coefficients as interpolated from data:"
    for j in range(cols):
        sign = ''
        if x[j]>0 and j>0:
            sign="+"
        elif x[j]>0:
            sign = " "
        print "%s%g*%s"%(sign,x[j],f_list[j])

    print "(measuring time in microseconds)"
    print "Sum of squares of residuals:",resids
    print "RMS error = %0.2g percent"%(math.sqrt(resids/len(A))*100.0)

def fit2(A,b):
    """ Relative error minimizer """
    def f(x):
        assert len(x) == len(A[0])
        resids = []
        for i in range(len(A)):
            sum = 0.0
            for j in range(len(A[0])):
                sum += A[i][j]*x[j]
            relative_error = (sum-b[i])/b[i]
            resids.append(relative_error)
        return resids
    ans = scipy.optimize.leastsq(f,[0.0]*len(A[0]))
    # print "ans:",ans
    if len(A[0])==1:
        x = [ans[0]]
    else:
        x = ans[0]
    resids = sum([r*r for r in f(x)])
    return (x,resids,0,0)
```

**UPDATE 1:** Even more confusing!

I checked the [python implementation of `intobject`](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/intobject.c), and it looks like it is supposed to be linear:

```
/* Convert an integer to a decimal string.  On many platforms, this
   will be significantly faster than the general arbitrary-base
   conversion machinery in _PyInt_Format, thanks to optimization
   opportunities offered by division by a compile-time constant. */
static PyObject *
int_to_decimal_string(PyIntObject *v) {
    char buf[sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT/3+6], *p, *bufend;
    long n = v->ob_ival;
    unsigned long absn;
    p = bufend = buf + sizeof(buf);
    absn = n < 0 ? 0UL - n : n;
    do {
        *--p = '0' + (char)(absn % 10);
        absn /= 10;
    } while (absn);
    if (n < 0)
        *--p = '-';
    return PyString_FromStringAndSize(p, bufend - p);
}
```

Comment: You may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835857/python-long-multiplication) relevant.  It's not clear to me why you'd necessarily expect `int("1"*n)` to be linear in `n`, since an increase in `n` increases the numerical value of `int("1"*n)` by a factor of 10.  As mentioned on the other question, the slowdown is likely due to the conversion from decimal to binary (or vice versa when using `repr`), on which see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418332/computational-complexity-of-base-conversion) and [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21736/).

Comment: @BretBarn Factor of 10 here is not relevant -- I expected the conversion to be a simple "convert->multiply->add" routine repeated `n` times. For example I can write the `int2str` as `while num > 0: result += str(num %10); num /= 10`, which clearly takes `n` steps, where `n` is the number of digits. This will make the routine `O(n)`, while python implementation is not. Thanks for the link though!!!

Comment: @RafazZ Have you benchmarked your proposed `int2str()`. I suspect that it will not be `O(n)`. I have been experimenting with a version of it on my machine, and it is roughly behaving `O(n^2)` just like `repr()`. Where `n` refers to the length of the string, not the value of `n` itself. Which makes me wonder whether focusing on string length is really the issue. Perhaps what matters for this algorithm is the size of the integer.

Comment: I was expecting it being quadratic, because I think there is something deep inside Python, but my implementation reports back as linear (check the sample code [here](https://github.com/zafartahirov/MOOCs/blob/master/MIT_ocw/6.006F11/JUNK/timing_exc.py)). I am even more confused now :( Any explanation?

Comment: Oh scratch my previous comment, I misread the results -- my implementation also reports back as quadratic! The question is why?

Comment: @RafazZ: You are assuming that the various operations in your algorithm take constant time, but I don't think that is true.  In particular, I think doing `num /= 10` will take longer when `num` is larger.  This is mentioned in one of the questions I linked to.

Comment: @BrenBarn I can see it myself that the division, `repr`, and some other functions are nonlinear, and stating the obvious is not really helpful. Please, read the question -- it is not "What is the complexity?" or "Confirm my benchmarks are correct". It is "Please, explain why is it the way it is". The complexities are reported long ago on different sites, including [the one I use](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/readings/python-cost-model/) -- it is the explanation behind it I am interested in

Comment: @RafazZ To convert an integer to a string (or vice versa) you have to do some math -- math similar to your proposed `int2str()`. This tells us that the speed of the algorithm a function of the mathematical operations, which in turn are a function of **integer size**, not the number of digits in the stringified integer. Some of those mathematical operations (notably division) are `O(n^2)` with respect to the integer size. So your question -- Why isn't this `O(n)` with respect to **string length** -- is focusing on the wrong thing. That's not the best explanation, but it's a start.

Comment: @RafazZ: I don't see what you're getting at.  The various other questions I've linked to explain the time complexity of various operations that need to be done to stringify an int.  If your question is about the math behind that it's probably off-topic for this site.  Also, your question just says you "assumed" a certain time complexity, without explaining why, so it's hard to know what kind of explanation you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I see how it would be quadratic in the core now -- the reason I "assumed" linear I did not assume that `str()` would use division in its core (maybe LUT), and also because most assemblies have an atomic instruction for `div`, meaning that any compiled code would take fixed number of steps for division, which didn't really trigger anything in my mind